# Prevent function to return before async call is finished using the extend keyword

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Code is something like this.

```
//Extending a Nativescript module.      
var test = ImageProvider.extend({

  getImage: function(url){

    //async call to get the image from cache
    cacheService.getImage(url,  
      function(image){
         return image
      }, 
      function(error){ 
        return null 
    });
 }
});
```

How do i prevent the getImage function to return before image is provided ?
I prefer not to use typescript or babel to solve the problem. But please advice if needed. (also tried babel,typescript without any luck)
I have tried to use await and yield by setting:

```
"android": {"v8Flags": "--expose_gc --use_strict --harmony"}
```

in the package.json file without success.

A sample giving errors using yield

```
"use strict" 

function onNavigationgTo(args){ 
  yield test(); 
}

function* test(){
  return 1;
}
```

It works without error before i add the yield keyword. Using yield gives the following. SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word File : "unknown"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: And how did your code look like when you tried to use `yield` and `await`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara : I am extending (overriding in java) a function. So i do not hav full controll over the function. Then i would have used promises or callback. I see that it is also suggested yield, await and fibers (can not find process object). I have tried them but can not get them to work as expected in Nativescript. (all give me errors). So i think the problem is related to how this should be done in Nativescript. Since it should be possible with await etc i es 6. Nativescript uses es 5 as far as i know. But hoped with the --harmony flagg it should be possible.

Comment: @t.niese I have updated with a sample using the yield. Do you see any problems in code. It looks like i am not able to use generators.

Answer (score 0):

You use [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this.

```
var test = ImageProvider.extend({
  getImage: function(url){
    //async call to get the image from cache
    return new Promise(function(resolve,  reject) {
        cacheService.getImage(url,  
          function(image){
             resolve(image);
          }, 
          function(error){ 
            reject(error);
        });
    });
 }
});
```

then use it like this

```
test.getImage('http://...').then(function(image) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Native promises are supported by all major browsers.. except IE (It is supported by edge).
If you want a wider browser support, I recommend using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The getImage is extended from ImageProvider. It is up to the module to handle the actuall loading off the image and display it. So i don't think i can use promises in this case. (have thought about it). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Stavanger75 This handles image loading just fine. I believe displaying it must be done manually as there are no selectors or any way for ImageProvider to know where to display the image.

Comment: Kaspars: extend means override in Java.  So when getImage returns an image. The imageprovider will handle how it is displayed. https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface.html.

Comment: @Stavanger75 Is ImageProvider a custom class? Can you provide the source code for it? Having it handle both retrieval and displaying seems like an odd design choice.

Comment: The code provided was just for illustration (to keep it as simple at possible). You can check out TileProvider.getTile(). I have extended that in Nativescript and it is working but returning before a tile (image) is provided. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably not a good idea since it would block the UI while the program is loading something. This problem is most usually solved through either a callback or a promise/custom task implementation. Example with a callback:

```
getImage: function(url, callback){
    //async call to get the image from cache
    cacheService.getImage(url,  
      function(image){
         callback({ image: image, error: null });
      }, 
      function(error){ 
        callback({ image: null, error: error });
    });
 }
```

And the usage will then look like

```
ImageProvider.getImage('someurl.png', function(result) {
    if (result.image) {
        // image has successfully downloaded -- good!
    }
    else {
        // handle result.error
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to use something like yield og await to not block the UI. But i am not able to get it working in Nativescript. I am using extend keyword(override in Java) and is not able to use promise or callback on the function. If their is a way to do this in Nativescript please advice.